# Epsilon definition in JavaCC

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javacc

How can I define Epsilon in JavaCC??
I'm trying smething like

```
< EPSILON: "">
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a token to match the empty string if the token manager then switches to a lexical state in which at least one character will be consumed before returning to the state in which the empty string was matched. So:

```
TOKEN : {
    < EMPTY : "" >
    : MATCH_NON_EMPTY // change state, or infinite matches of the empty string could result
}

<MATCH_NON_EMPTY>
TOKEN : {
    < NON_EMPTY : ~[] >
}

void Start() : { } {
    <EMPTY> <NON_EMPTY>
}
```

That will work fine given any single-character input.

I should mention a caveat, however. It seems that a match of `EOF` is considered to be "longer" than a match of the empty string, so an empty string cannot be matched immediately before `EOF` without some lexical action magic when `EOF` is matched.

Comment: I am not quite sure but would you need to switch back to the DEFAULT state for example once you have recognized <EMPTY> and <NON_EMPTY> respectively?

Comment: @marcwellman It's not necessary, since the <EOF> token will be recognized in any state (I think!). But yes, if you want to return to the same state in which the empty string was originally matched (in order to match it again, for example), you'd need to switch back to the DEFAULT state, at least in this example.

Comment: I see .. I am still having troubles with my parser but your post did help me a lot! I right now trying to transform a left-recursive grammar into a non-left-recursive one. And there I have to deal with empty words ..

Comment: It seems that I have found an alternative solution for the epsilon-problem since your approach did not fully work for me. I was just using an empty production rule of the form 'void Empty() : { } { some Java code here }'. This seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Since I was also looking for a way to use the empty word *epsilon* I came up with the following approach.

I simply used an empty production rule such as:

```
void Empty () : { } { System.out.prntln("epsilon"); }
```

Hope it works - at least for now it seems so ...

**Addendum:**

It works pretty fine :)

Comment: That's okay depending on what you're trying to do. This will not produce an "empty" token without some additional help, however. If you need a token to represent the empty input sequence, you'll need to manually create it and link it into the token stream.